# How to remove all but a set of characters from a string?

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove all characters from a string except for '+', '-', and '.'. These values can be stored in an array or hard coded into the program. Is there anyway to do this with a specific function or with regex?

Comment: The answer to your question is probably *yes*, but 1) provide an example of what you want to achieve, 2) show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, regular expression has a syntax for **negated character classes**.

No, I'm not going to give you the complete solution. Look it up in the regexp manual. It's so basic, I do not get why you need to ask, when it's right in every documentation. Where's the question?

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about that. Yeah, I see now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex with a string replace.

```
/[^\+|\-|\.]/g
```

This is a bit overkill. I would instead just foreach over the string and build up a new string by only adding the desired characters. Something like:

```
String text = retrieveTextToProcess();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (char ch: text.toCharArray()) {
    if(isDesiredCharacter(ch)) {
       sb.Append(ch);
    }
}
```

You will need to write the retrieveTextToProcess and isDesiredCharacter methods.